# Rhythm Heaven Remix Editor 3: Custom JSON file returning 'Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name'

Tags: json

So, I'm just trying to get some custom sounds in RHRE3 working, when I kept getting 'Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name' when I tried to launch the program with the custom code.

THE CUE JSON:

```
  {
  "type": "cue",
  "id": "oneTwo/homestar_one",
  "deprecatedIDs": [],
  "name": "one",
  "duration": 1.0,
  "repitchable": false,
  "fileExtension": "wav",
  "baseBpm": 105.0,
  }
```

UPDATE: Turns out the trailing comma at the end wasn't allowed in JSON, but now I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting 'Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries'.

Comment: That trailing comma on the next-to-last line is not allowed in JSON.

Comment: Ah, thanks! But, now I'm facing an 'Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries' error when I try to run the custom stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This a sample incorrect,

> ('{' (code 123)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries.

```
[
    {},
    {}   // missing comma between second item and third item.
    {}
]
```